# How do I make undo/redo in <textarea> to react on 1 word at a time, word by word or character by character?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea, undo

How do I make undo/redo in textarea to react on 1 word at a time, word by word or character by character? Not to all at once.

Right now this function I have works but it reacts to all the words in the textarea at once and that is the wrong way to function in my case. I need it to react word by word and not all words at once, so that it works like a text editor. I am using Chrome, and I need it to work word by word or character by character for any web browser or at least for the major ones.

**NOTE:** Do not advice me to use editable div because in this case editable div I can not use with the other functions I have on the page. I need it for `<textarea>` and nothing else.

**JavaScript:**

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function Undo() { document.execCommand("undo", false, null); }
function Redo() { document.execCommand("redo", false, null); }
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="button" onmouseup="Undo();CopyTextDivText();" value=" &laquo;--&laquo; Undo " />
<input type="button" onmouseup="Redo();CopyTextDivText();" value=" Redo &raquo;--&raquo; " />
<textarea name="text" id="text" class="content" rows="34" cols="104" wrap="soft"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a custom undo and redo, here's something to get you started.  I simply save a state every time the user types 'space'.

```js
saveState = [];
var saveI = 0;

$('#inputRegion').on("keydown", function (event) {
 if (event.which == " ".charCodeAt(0)) {
  saveState.push($(this).val());
  saveI = saveState.length -1;
  debug();
 }
});

function triggerUndo () {
 if (saveI >= 0) {
  saveI--;
  $("#inputRegion").val(saveState[saveI]);
 }
 debug();
}

function triggerRedo () {
 if (saveI < saveState.length) {
  saveI++;
  $("#inputRegion").val(saveState[saveI]);
 }
 debug();
}

function debug() {
 return;
 //removed, used for debugging.
 console.log(saveI);
 console.log(saveState);
}
```

```css
textarea {
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="inputRegion"></textarea>
<br />
<button onclick="triggerUndo()">Undo</button>
<button onclick="triggerRedo()">Redo</button>
```

Comment: I have tried it out and it still does not do it. The idea you say that is save seach time 'space' is used, is a really good idea for the undo, if it worked. Also since it did not save for the undo, the 'redo' refuses to work too. Undo works as default with all text at once and not word by word or character by character either. @nfnneil

Comment: Now if you idea and your codes do work then it must be some detail that may be wrong in the codes. I will try to find why it does not work, but if you could help me to find why it would be great since you made those codes, you understand them better then me. @nfnneil

Answer (score -1):

I'm trying this code.

```
<style type="text/css">
  #knpmain div{
  display: inline-table;
  width: 280px;
 }
 .dnr {
  display: block;
 }
 button {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 4px;
 }
 #nu { width: 264px; }
 #lghtnr {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  font-size: 2.0em;
 }
</style>

<h1>Number pad</h1>
<div id="knpmain">
 <div>
  <div>
    <textarea id="lghtnr" type="text"></textarea> 
  </div>
 </div>
 <div> 
  <div class="bnr">
    <button id="sj" value="7" onclick="up(this.value)">7</button>
    <button id="at" value="8" onclick="up(this.value)">8</button>
    <button id="ni" value="9" onclick="up(this.value)">9</button>
    <button id="cl" onclick="del()">C</button>
  </div>
  <div class="bnr">
    <button id="fy" value="4" onclick="up(this.value)">4</button>
    <button id="fe" value="5" onclick="up(this.value)">5</button>
    <button id="se" value="6" onclick="up(this.value)">6</button>
    <button id="ud"  onclick="rad()">&#8630;</button>
  </div>
  <div class="bnr">
    <button id="et" value="1" onclick="up(this.value)">1</button>
    <button id="tv" value="2" onclick="up(this.value)">2</button>
    <button id="tr" value="3" onclick="up(this.value)">3</button>
    <button id="rd" onclick="rdo()">&#8631;</button>
  </div>
  <div class="bnr">
    <button id="nu" value="0" onclick="up(this.value)">0</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<script>
var act = new Array(); var po=0;

function rad() {
      var inp = document.getElementById("lghtnr").innerHTML;
      var tmp = inp.substr(0, inp.length-1);
  document.getElementById("lghtnr").innerHTML = tmp;
  po--;
  console.log("inp:" + act + " StrL:" + inp.length + " Po:" + po);
}
function rdo() {
 if(po < act.length) {
  var inp = document.getElementById("lghtnr").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("lghtnr").innerHTML = inp + act[po];
  po++;
 }
}
function up(v) {
  var inp = document.getElementById("lghtnr").innerHTML;
  var newinp = inp + v;
  document.getElementById("lghtnr").innerHTML = newinp;
  po++;
  act.push(v);
  console.log("inp:" + act + " StrL:" + newinp.length + " Po:" + po);
}

function del() {
  document.getElementById("lghtnr").innerHTML = "";
  po = 0; act = [];
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please add some description regarding your answer, otherwise it looks like `copy` & `paste`. Please see this first [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: It does not react if I use the keyboard, but I must use the buttons in the page. I need it to work if I use to write with the keyboard as well, not only by bushing on screen buttons.